# Is limit function of continuous even functions always continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Limit function of Uniform Continuous functions (pointwise converge) is always continuous.

It is the fact.

Limit function of continuous functions is not always continuous (am I right?)

However, for the case that **limit function of continuous even functions**, what can do we conclude it?

In other words, **limit function of continuous even functions is always continuous even not in the case of uniform convergence?**

I am pondering this subject for long time, but it is very confusing me.

---

Actually, I have this problem.

I am having hard time to solve this problems.
$C$ denotes set of functions, $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is continuous.
please help me with this.

---

Let $C_{e}([-1, 1],\mathbb{R})$ denote the set of even function in $C([-1,1],\mathbb{R})$.

[a] Show that $C_e$ is closed and not dense in $C$.

[b] Show that the even polynomials are dense in $C_e$, but not in $C$.

---

**The part of solution is,**

@qyong,

Since it's been a while, I'm assuming you're still stuck on the problem. I am assuming you have endowed $C([-1,1])$ with the uniform continuity metric for ease. Let's start with a lemma, from which, as @Ian suggested, the solutions should follow nicely:

**Lemma**: Let $f_i \in C([-a,a])$. Given a sequence of even, real-valued, continuous functions $f_i : [-a,a] \to \mathbb{R}$ that converge to $f$, $f$ must also be even.

*Proof:* Assume the hypothesis, that we have a sequence $f_{i}(x)$ of continuous, even, real-valued functions that converge uniformly to some $f(x)$ for $x \in [-a,a]$. Assume $f(x)$ is not even. Then we know that for sufficiently large $i \in \mathbb{N}^+$, $|f_{i}(x) \to f(x)| < \epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. From which, we also have $|f_{i}(-x) \to f(-x)| < \epsilon$ as well. But evenness of the $f_{i}$ also tells us that $f_{i}(-x) = f_{i}(x)$, so that $|f_{i}(x) \to f(-x)| < \epsilon$. But since $f$ is not even, $f(x) \neq f(-x)$, which contradicts convergence of the $f_i$. QED

From this, we have:

[a]. $C_{e}$ contains all of it's limit points, since any $f_{i} \in C_{e}([-1,1], \mathbb{R})$ converges to an even $f$, which is also in $C_{e}([-1,1], \mathbb{R})$. Thus $C_e$ is closed.

[b]. Let $f \in C([-1,1], \mathbb{R})$. We can apply the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem since $[-1,1]$ is closed and bounded, i.e. for some even (again, by hypothesis) polynomial $P(x)$, we have $|P(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$. So by our lemma above, $f$ must be even, i.e. $f \in C_{e}([-1,1], \mathbb{R})$. Thus if we let $P_{e}$ be the set of all even polynomials, by the above argument in conjunction with Weierstrass's Theorem, we have that $\overline{P_e} = C_e$, so it is dense in $C_e$, but $\overline{C_e} \neq C$ so the set of even polynomials cannot be dense in $C$.

**By @Alex**

---

However, how about, not in the uniform continuous?????????

I think this solution is not perfect........

Comment: $f_n(x) = x^{2n}$ on $[-1, 1]$ is a sequence of even functions.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, and the standard counterexample almost works.

The standard counterexample is $f_n(x) = x^n$ on $[0,1]$. Simply extending this counterexample, and keeping only the even functions, gives you the functions $$f_n:[-1, 1]\to \mathbb R\\ f_n(x) = x^{2n}$$

Which converges to a non-continuous function.

Comment: I think this statement might be wrong. $f_n(x)$ is not continuous even function on [0, 1] in this case. The reason is that x=0 is not defined on this function.

Comment: @MathforyourLife I don't understand what you are trying to say. $f_n$ is a continuous function on $[-1, 1]$. It is well defined for $x=0$. And the limit function of $f_n$ also exists and is equal to $0$ for $x=0$.

Comment: I am sorry. I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

The pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions $(f_n)$ may not be continuous you're right. Take the example of the sequence of functions defined on $[0,1]$ by $f_n(x)=x^n$. The sequence converges pointwise to the function $f$ equal to $0$ on $[0,1)$ and to $1$ at $x=1$. Obviously $f$ is discontinuous at $1$.

$f_n(x) = \vert x \vert^n$ is even and continuous and the limit is not continuous.

To be even has little thing to do with continuity. Imagine that a sequence of continuous functions $(f_n)$ is defined on the interval $[0,a]$ with $a > 0$. If the functions converges pointwise to a discontinuous function, the sequence $(\overline{f}_n)$ defined on $[-a,a]$ by $\overline{f}_n(x)=f_n(x)$ for $x \ge 0$ and $\overline{f}_n(x)=f_n(-x)$ for $x \le 0$ is even and is also discontinuous.

Comment: Your example is right.

Comment: So, Can we conclude that Ce is closed? We do not know that f(limit function) is always continuous in the problem.